# How to change the edit button action in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UITableView` where in I have added a left navigation bar `UIBarButtonItem` to edit contents of the table. When I click on the edit button I get delete buttons before each of my `UITableViewCell`.

I have written a `selector` for the edit button, but when I click on it by default it shows the delete button before every cell. What I need is, when my edit button is clicked instead of delete button a disclosure button should be shown on every cell right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on table view editing mode in the edit button selector?
Perhaps by using something like:

```
[tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
```

Instead you could loop through all cells of the table and set the accessoryType

```
for (int section = 0; section < [tableView numberOfSections]; section++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
        NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];
        cell.accesoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
}
```

Although I am not sure if this works when cells are pooled and reused.